# What is causing this Permission Denied error for my EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have been trying to connect to my EC2 all day, but keep getting error

> Permission Denied (Publickey,Gssapi-Keyex,Gssapi-With-Mic)

So far I have done everything outlined in these articles, one from the AWS troubleshooting page to no avail.

This is the debug info I get when trying to connect:

```
➜  ~ ssh -vvv -i ~/path/to/pem/key.pem address.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to address.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kurt/path/to/pem/key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kurt/path/to/pem/key.pem-cert type -1
.
.
.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
kurt@address.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Done in Terminal on OSX Catalina

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-permission-denied-publickey 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/

Comment: ssh command should be like `ssh -vvv -i ~/path/to/pem/key.pem user@address.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @AchyutVyas the connection is successfully established with or without the user@ in front

Comment: @Kurt you are using DNS name to connect, in case there is trouble with DNS. Can you try with IP address, plus  this `kurt@address.compute.amazonaws.com`, it doesn't seem like user with your name is already there unless you added one. Default username If it is `ubuntu` OS, username is `ubuntu` , if Amazon Linux it is `ec2-user` and for others  you can check this page [Get information about your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html#connection-prereqs-get-info-about-instance). I am assuming you already  changed permissions on the key to `600`